# Can't find SuperSU on Google Play

Tags: rooting, supersu

I rooted my phone with SuperSU ZIP, and I want to update the app, but I didn't find it on Google Play. I also tried manually creating this URL but it returns 404.

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As of October 1, 2018, SuperSU has been removed from Google Play](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/10/01/supersu-removed-play-store/). However its pro key (US$3.99) is still available.

The latest version of SuperSU is 2.82 SR5, you can find it on [this XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/2014-09-02-supersu-v2-05-t2868133). However, as Android evolves, SuperSU is no longer the best choice for rooting. Instead [Magisk](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/magisk/info) is recommended for Android 5.0 or newer. SuperSU is still good for Android 4.4 or older systems.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman another point pro Magisk even on LOS is: when you have to flash the device again (e.g. a non-delta update), all your "systemless changes" to the system stay intact: root, the hosts file, "removed" apps… It's not just "systemless root", it's rather more even "systemless system", so to speak :) Plus, Magisk is still maintained while SuperSU is not. I've followed iBug's advice and flashed Magisk after flashing LOS to my new device. I'm not disappointed.

Comment: @iBug I have a last question to bug you with: since I run microG, there's a support library (MapsV1) distributed as flashable .zip I need to install, otherwise a particular app refuses to run. Is there some way to install this support library systemlessly?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I think it doesn't matter if that package is flashed to system. If you really want it systemless maybe take a look [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/module-nanomod-5-0-20170405-microg-t3584928).

Comment: @iBug After a clean flash, Magisk works flawlessly. I had to change the kernel because the stock LOS one didn't have the mount namespace feature backported, but even MagiskHide does its job as advertised. Needless to say, your answer got an upvote. I'll start to flag obsolete comments for deletion now.